# How to auto increment duplicate values by sequence of repetitions

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add an indication of the number of sequence of repetitions of integers in `my_list`:

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,
           20,40,50,15,20,20,20,50,50]
#my_list.sort()
dup_list = []


for i in range (len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in dup_list:
        dup_list.append(my_list[i])
    else:
        j=1
        res = True
        while res:
            val = my_list[i]+j*0.1
            if val  not in dup_list:
                dup_list.append(val)
                res = False
            j+=1 

print(dup_list)
```

the result that I obtain

```
[20, 20.1, 20.2, 30, 20.3, 30.1, 40, 50, 15, 11, 20.4, 40.1, 50.1, 
 15.1, 20.5, 20.6, 20.7, 50.2, 50.3]
```

The result that I Look for:

```
[20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 30.0, 20.1, 30.1, 40.0, 50.0, 15.0, 11.0, 20.2, 
 40.1, 50.1, 15.1, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 50.2, 50.2]
```

Comment: What if there are more than 10 groups of a specific figure? `20.10`? It's unlikely that your dataset is that big, but are you aware that at some point floating point precision would cause errors in this representation? Wouldn't you be better off picking a better data structure, for example a list with number & group tuples? (FYI, re: floating point problems, try asking Python what the result for `.1 + .1 + .1` is and be horrified)

Comment: Your desired format has the issues that people are pointing out. Why not pick a better format like `(20,1), (20,2), (20,3), (30,1), (20,4), (30,2) ...`? i.e. tuples of `(value, count)` Or if you only want the final counts, not the running count, use `collections.Counter` already (a specialized dict for counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, floating point arithmetic is prone to precision issues.Anyway, you can keep track of the current value of every unique item by using a dictionary:

```py
x = [20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 11, 20, 40, 50, 15, 20, 20, 20, 50, 50]
current_values = dict(zip(x, x))

new_x = []
last_seen = x[0]
for item in x:
     if item != last_seen:
         current_values[last_seen] = round(current_values[last_seen] + 0.1, 2)
         last_seen = item
     new_x.append(current_values[item])
```

Result:

```py
In [3]: new_x == desired
Out[3]: True
```

Note that since you haven't specified yet what you'd want to do in the case there is more than 10 duplicates, right now you'd start getting `21.0`, etc. This should be enough to help you solve your problem and give you something to modify if you need.

Comment: Note that this logic breaks when there are more than 10 groups of a single digit - the 11th group of `20` won't be `20.10`, but incorrectly wrap around to `21.0` (apart from other mistakes creeping in due to floating point issues)

Comment: Sure, but OP hasn't specified what they want to do in that case, so I'm leaving it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary `dup` that you use to keep track of the duplicate values as you iterate over `my_list`. Update `dup` whenever a new number is encountered or if a number that is a duplicate but different from the number preceding it:

```
out = [my_list[0]]
dup = {out[0]: 0}
for i,j in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]):
    if j in dup:
        if i!=j:
            dup[j] += 0.1
    else:
        dup[j] = 0
    out.append(j+dup[j])
```

Output:

```
out = [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 30.0, 20.1, 30.1, 40.0, 50.0, 15.0, 11.0, 20.2, 40.1, 50.1, 15.1, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 50.2, 50.2]
```

Comment: Note that this logic breaks when there are more than 10 groups of a single digit - the 11th group of `20` won't be `20.10`, but incorrectly wrap around to `21.0` - and floating point issues here as well.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that there are 10 groups of a number if OP's deciding to modify their data like this. Same with the floating point issue. It'll be imprecise but I don't think having a precise 20.3 or 20.5 is OP's goal.